# intellisense not working properly on unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, autocomplete, visual-studio-2019

my intellisense does not auto complete my unity related code (input, rigidbody etc) and does not give the same things colors, in addition it does not highlight errors at all, it is on 2021.1.1.7f1 and i use visual studios for c#. in case it matters I am a starting coder and used this video to teach myself:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZpJzpE2lQ

I have tried using related videos on youtube, I have tried switching the external script editor, and I have no idea where to even start.

thank you very much

Comment: visual studio code or visual studio? both are different. In visual studio before installing using installer you will get an option of selecting extensions. Therefore you get unity extension. If you are in visual studio:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity. If you are in visual studio code:- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity. Read this integration guide to get an idea

Answer (score 1):

Running C# scripts requires Omnisharp ecosystem that enhances the c# experience. You have to make sure that you have installed dot net in your local machine and the editor uses omnisharp. In visual studio code, there is a fire-like icon appears when a dot net project is opened in your editor.

Comment: is that for visual studios too? I do not use VSC